# Boost::convex_hull of scattered 2-D points in STL container

Tags: c++, boost, std, convex-hull, boost-geometry

I have a vector of 2-D points. Lets assume they are of the form std::pair<int,int>. I want to use boost to calculate the convex hull. That's the question. How do I do that?

The only documentation I have found is like a graduate text for a course in rationale and trivia.

Fill in the BLANKS:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

// BLANK boost include-files
// #include <boost/geometry.hpp>
// #include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp> // Noop.
// #include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp>
// BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOOST_TUPLE_CS(cs::cartesian)

int main() {
    // Serving suggestion
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> A{ { 0,3 },{ 1,4 },{ 2,2 },{ 1,0 }, \
    {0,0},{ 2,0 },{ 0,1 },{ 0,2 },{ 3,1 },{ 3,3 },{ 4,4 },{ 4,3 },{ 4,2 } };

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> the_hull; // Fill this, please.

 // BLANK - Boost magic goes here.

    // Print convex hull of A
    for (auto h: the_hull) {
        std::cout << h.first << "," << h.second << "\n";
    }
    std::cout<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Note to VC++ users. I had a metric tonne of trouble getting the answers below to compile, using VC++ 2017.  I finally got it working. I re-installed boost, using the windows binaries for boost 1.66.  Next I had to add the following two lines to the project properties

```
_SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS;_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

The IDE treats those "warnings" as fatal. It is not sufficient to disable all warnings. Furthermore, some of the "deprecation warnings" appear to be finger-wagging from Microsoft, not officially deprecated C++ things.

Comment: Note on the linked question: it's just not related.  The fact that is "has no accepted answer" is mainly because it was a pretty poor question, the requirements ill-conceived and the OP didn't bother to accept (in fact I hope he abandoned that whole plan). You can serve the community better by accepting an answer. Several on-point answers exist now, so I won't add to it anymore :)

Comment: @sehe I will accept an answer when I get one to compile on my computer - maybe before. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do this without copying data from a container to a `multi_point` and vice versa. 
You have to register the vector container and the pair as a `multi_point` and `point` entity.

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/multi/geometries/register/multi_point.hpp> 

#include<iostream>

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(decltype(std::pair<int, int>{}), int, cs::cartesian, first, second)
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_MULTI_POINT(decltype(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>{}))

int main(){
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> A{
        { 0,3 },{ 1,4 },{ 2,2 },{ 1,0 }, { 0,0 }, { 2,0 }, { 0,1 }, { 0,2 },
        { 3,1 },{ 3,3 },{ 4,4 },{ 4,3 }, { 4,2 } 
    };
    std::cout << "A: " << boost::geometry::wkt(A) << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> B;
    boost::geometry::convex_hull(A, B);
    std::cout << "B: " << boost::geometry::wkt(B) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
A: MULTIPOINT((0 3),(1 4),(2 2),(1 0),(0 0),(2 0),(0 1),(0 2),(3 1),(3 3),(4 4),(4 3),(4 2))
B: MULTIPOINT((0 0),(0 3),(1 4),(4 4),(4 2),(2 0),(0 0)
```

This works in Fedora 27, gcc 7.2.1, clang++ 4.0.1, Boost 1.64

---

For Visual C++ 2017, Boost 1.66, it is necessary to add these to properties/C C++/Preprocessor/Preprocessor Definitions

```
 _SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS;_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

The Visual Studio IDE treats those "warnings" as fatal. It is not sufficient to disable all warnings. Furthermore, some of the "deprecation warnings" appear to be Microsoft specific, not officially deprecated C++ things.

Comment: @JiveDadson Does this help: http://rextester.com/BKK45485 (that's boost 1.60 though, but uses MSVC 19.00.23506)

Comment: @sehe - Still no joy. Installing a new boost now.

Comment: @sehe Hip hip, hooray!

Answer (score 2):

You can convert vector of points into multipoint type.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOOST_TUPLE_CS(cs::cartesian)

int main(){
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_type;

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> A{ { 0,3 },{ 1,4 },{ 2,2 },{ 1,0 },
    {0,0},{ 2,0 },{ 0,1 },{ 0,2 },{ 3,1 },{ 3,3 },{ 4,4 },{ 4,3 },{ 4,2 } };

    boost::geometry::model::multi_point<point_type> pts;
    for (const auto& pt : A){
        pts.emplace_back(pt.first,pt.second);   
    }

    boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_type> poly;
    boost::geometry::convex_hull (pts, poly);

    std::cout << boost::geometry::wkt(poly) << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> the_hull; // Fill this, please.
    for (auto it = poly.outer().begin(); it != poly.outer().end(); ++it)
        the_hull.emplace_back(it->x(), it->y());

    // Print convex hull of A
    for (auto h: the_hull) {
        std::cout << h.first << "," << h.second << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't make it compile, what include do you use? I get a `HIS_OPERATION_IS_NOT_OR_NOT_YET_IMPLEMENTED` from Boost.Geometry.

Comment: `<boost/geometry.hpp>` , `<boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>` and `<boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>`, boost version 1.64 .

Comment: ok, I posted the full  working code based in your answer. I edited your answer, reject the change if you don't want it.

Comment: Also, do you think there is a way to do this without copying the points to a polygon? a container of points should model a Geometry.

Comment: It is the simplest solution I figured out. I have no idea how to avoid copying points.

Comment: @alfC I still get a skillion undecipherable errors from Visual C++ 2017 using boost 1.65.1

Comment: @alfC Eschew early optimization.

Comment: @alfC I get a ton of errors even with the body of main() removed. Just the headers and an empty int main() { return 0;}  VC++ 2017, boost 1.65.1

Comment: @alfC - See added bit at the end of the main question.

Comment: @JiveDadson, Sounds like a bug in Geometry when used in Visual C++. I am not familiar with VC++ and `stdafx.hpp`. Also see (and try?) my new answer which directly does what you want, without copying the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can register your point type `std::pair<int,int>` with the BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D macro and then use it. And you don't need multipoint. Here one example. Hope it helps:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

using Point = std::pair<int,int>;
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(Point, int, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian, first, second)

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> v{ { 0,3 },{ 1,4 },{ 2,2 },{ 1,0 },{ 0,0 },{ 2,0 },{ 0,1 },{ 0,2 },{ 3,1 },{ 3,3 },{ 4,4 },{ 4,3 },{ 4,2 } };

    using Polygon = boost::geometry::model::polygon<Point>;
    Polygon poly, hull;
    poly.outer().assign(v.begin(), v.end());
    boost::geometry::convex_hull (poly, hull);

    using boost::geometry::dsv;
    std::cout << "polygon" << dsv(poly) << std::endl
              << "hull: " << dsv(hull) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here the example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/j2XkmLivqcy6EtdU